# Impossible to login after crash

Tags: fedora, login, crash

I am using Fedora 16. I have downloaded MySQL Server and tried to start it; while doing so my Fedora hung. So I shutdown by pressing the power button. When I try to log in next time then this error occurs:

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong.A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.Please contact a system administrator

How do I recover my Fedora?

Comment: It says "Unable to recovery please contact your administrator"? That seems unlikely, unless it's a local customization

Comment: I forgot exact error message

Comment: Then try again, and come back with the exact error message. Is this after you type your password?

Comment: I have edited my post and posted a correct error message. Reopen this post and help me.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek turns out this message wasn't a joke .. Just found a link on google http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=272374

Answer (score 1):

reboot into single user mode
press <kbd>A</kbd> when you see the grub menu and add a <kbd>1</kbd> to the end of your kernel args.

from there you will be able to fix anything you need to